# Why is 1000 micrometer not a correct representation of a prefix?

Tags: conventions, notation, units

Why is 1000 micrometer not a correct representation of a prefix?

I ask because I recently took an entrance exam with a multiple-choice question which went along the lines of

> which of the following is not a correct representation for prefixes: (A) 1mm, (B) 10km, (C) 1000 micrometer, (D) Both A and B.

and the stated answer was (C), but I don't know why.

Is it because when we write it in scientific form, it produces a double prefix which is not possible?

Comment: Was "micrometer" written as you wrote it or in symbols, µm?

Comment: Reminds me of 5000 mAh batteries haha

Comment: µm was written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more a matter of convention.

For example, it is quite conventional to speak about pressures of 1000 hPa. There are historical reasons for that.

Answer (score 1):

> which of the following is not a correct representation for prefixes: (A) 1mm, (B) 10km, (C) 1000 micrometer, (D) Both A and B.

The question is about *prefixes* and has nothing to do with the numbers. The three prefixes here are “m” for milli, “k” for kilo, and “micro” for micro. The proper representation of micro is “$\mu$”, not “micro”.

Comment: My bad, it was µm not micro. I couldn't find the symbol :/

Comment: In that case, the question as you have stated and corrected it makes no sense because all three prefixes are correctly represented.

Comment: The symbol $\mu$ is written \mu in MathJax. Other Greek letters are similar.

Answer (score 0):

Writing $1000\:\mu \rm m$ is not *wrong* as such, in the sense that there are plenty of contexts in which it can be used, or might even be the best representation for that length. (As a rule, the best notation is the one that adds the most clarity to the text.)

Presumably, your exam has singled out that notation because the length can also be expressed as $\rm 1\: mm$, which is definitely simpler (and, if (*if!*) you are using significant figures to express uncertainties, allows you to distinguish between $\rm 1\: mm$ and $\rm 1.000\: mm$, though it's also important to note that significant figures are a fairly coarse tool, and if you really care about uncertainties then you handle them explicitly).

The distinction is stronger in [engineering notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_notation), which does force you to incorporate the rough size of the number (i.e. to within a factor of 1000) into the SI prefix. However, in general, the preference for $\rm 1\: mm$ over $1000\:\mu \rm m$ is only a matter of choice of convention.

Comment: Thank you :D (for editing the post and answering)

Answer (score -1):

1000 micrometers is one millimeter

Comment: So, we try to simplify the expression as much as possible to produce the highest order prefix?

Comment: I mean it could also have been 0.000001 kilometer. Does that mean we follow the scientific notation rule which states there should only be 1 non-zero digit before the decimal point?

Comment: no rule. you can write "1000 micrometers". it's not conventional, but there's nothing wrong about it.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Also, if you don't mind, could you tell me why 9800 mm has 4 significant figures and not 2 (since trailing zeros aren't considered significant)? (i can't ask any more questions :/)

Comment: 9800 mm is ambiguous. The trailing zeros might or might not be significant. You'd need to write 9800 mm (4 sigfigs) or 9800 (2 sigfigs) or some such. This is rather messy and it's often better to signal the number of sig figs by writing $9.800\times 10^3$ mm or $9.8\times 10^3$ mm, or better still, just 9.800 m or 9.8 m.

Comment: So, would you recommend that we write every measurement in the form of its scientific notation to figure it out?

Comment: As a general rule, yes, but there are many exceptions. For example you may want to compare distances across a range of values from (say) 5 mm to 120 mm. It would be unhelpful to express lengths less than 10 mm as (say) 6 mm, but those over 10 mm as (say) $1.1 \times 10^1$ mm or $1.15 \times 10^2$ mm.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks :)